# Debugging JavaScript inserted later in the page

Tags: javascript, debugging, asp.net-core, browser

I want to debug an issue in my JavaScript code. However I don't have access to the source at the moment, but I want to debug it in my browser now.

The JavaScript piece of code I want to debug is in a view, added later to the page (.NET Core .cshtml view).

I can see that in the Elements tab in my browser, but not in the Source, so I can add breakpoints.

Is there a way for me to "search" for that code in the Source tab or to add a breakpoint through the Elements tab in the browser?

Comment: You can use `Ctrl-Shift-F` in Chrome DevTools (maybe others as well) to search through the entire code. If you click one of the results it should open in the Source tab.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful.